# placeholder'ы занимают больше высоты чем нужно

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui, dart-ui

Что мне сделать чтобы placeholder'ы занимали были одинакового размера с изображением? Без placeholder'ов `Card` такого-же размера как и изображение, так-что думаю что проблема с placeholder'ом

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: MasonryGridView.count(
          controller: _scrollController,
          crossAxisCount: columns,
          itemCount: images.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final image = images[index];

            return Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                    image: image.previewUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    width: image.previewWidth.toDouble(),
                    height: image.previewHeight.toDouble()));
          },
        ),
      ),
      _buildLoadingIndicator(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

[image: Скриншот приложения]